# Javascript alert box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using JavaScript

```
(ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Product Added Successfully!')", true);)
```

to show an alert box after the code enters a section of if/else block. But when I added a script manager and update panel to aspx page, the javascript functionality stopped working. So i used this statement:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Upload Photo');</script>");
```

even which did not work! Does anyone has an idea or solution to this problem.
Below is the code in the .cs file:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(uploadProductPhoto.HasFile)
            {
                int x = SaveProductPhoto();
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart
                    {
                        ProductName = txtProductName.Text,
                        ProductPrice = txtProductPrice.Text,
                        ProductImage = "~/ProductImages/" + uploadProductPhoto.FileName,
                        ProductDescription = txtProductDescription.Text,
                        CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue),
                        TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductQuantity.Text)
                    };

                    k.AddNewProduct();
                }
                ClearText();
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Product Added Successfully!')", true);
                //Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AddNewProducts.aspx?alert=success");
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Upload Product Photo!')", true);
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Upload Photo');</script>");
            }

        }

 private int SaveProductPhoto()
        {
            if(uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile==null)
            {
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('Please upload photo');</script>");
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please Upload Product Photo!')", true);
                return 1;
            }
                string filename = uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadProductPhoto.FileName);

                if(filename.Length>100)
                {
                    //Response.Write("<script>alert('File name should not exceed 100 characters');</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('File name should not exceed 100 characters')", true);
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(fileExt!=".jpg" && fileExt!=".jpeg" && fileExt!=".bmp" && fileExt!=".png")
                {
                    //Response.Write("<script>alert('Image file should be in .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp format!');</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Image file should be in .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp format!')", true);
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength>4000000)
                {
                    //Response.Write("<script>alert('File size should not be greater than 4 mb');</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('File size should not be greater than 4 mb')", true);
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    uploadProductPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + filename));
                    //Response.Write("<script>alert('Product added successfully!');</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Product added successfully!')", true);
                    return 0;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to show JavaScript alert? Why not just create a label and set its text to what you want. alerts are annoying.

Comment: Try ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", alert('Product Added Successfully!');", true);

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert("Product Added Successfully!");", true);

Comment: Try out with this Script.You can get it.

Comment: Tried it, Still not working! Does it have to do anything with the postback of the button not working in ajax update panel??